# Catch Execute Error and Continue (arcpy)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, error

I've got a script that does a number of Date/Time conversions using `arcpy.ConvertTimeField_Management`. A common issue that I need to handle is when the field is empty and an execute error is raised:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000192: Invalid value for Time Format = 'yyyyMMddHHmmss' - was not able to successfully convert any row's time field value
```

This error occurs when I use the try/except below; I'd like the script to ignore this error and continue. Any ideas?

`try:
    results = arcpy.ConvertTimeField_management(SA_TEN_GOV_els, "START_DATE", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", "START_DAT", "DATE", "'Not Used'")
except:
    print results.getMessages() 
    pass`

Comment: Create a layer that contains non-empty rows and perform the calculation on that.

Comment: Negative, unless you switch to update cursor and split input.

Comment: I agree with @FelixIP, the ConvertTimeField command operates at a featureClass level, so it either works or it fails. If you need to ignore errors but keep the good values, you'll need to handle it yourself in a cursor. Or, pre-select the features as Michael and Emil suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael suggested, first creating a layer file of populated rows should do the trick.

Before your code, create a variable with the proper SQL query, and then create your layer file. Execute your time conversion on your layer file.

code:

```
sql = '"START_DATE" IS NOT NULL'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (SA_TEN_GOV_els, "lyr", sql)
arcpy.ConvertTimeField_management("lyr", "START_DATE", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", "START_DAT", "DATE", "'Not Used'")
```